# How to make simple book pages using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am pretty new to programming and I just signed up to ask a simple question.

**How do you do a simple "book" page with javascript?**

Like, when I click on the "P2" button, the P2 I writed appears, and the P3 button appears on the bottom right too. I don't even need any animations or whatever. I tryed to put all the story on a document.write . But of course, div and some html tags aren't working.

I want to do this without making the user to load another page to continue with the story.

Thank you I hope you understand what I want to do, and have a good day/night.

I may need to use ajax, so I will check that out, but if there is an easy way with javascript I'll apreciate some advices.

Comment: did you try something ?

Comment: What, you want us to write the code for you? Because we won't.

Comment: You are probably talking about `ajax` usage, but we need to see what you have tried already. If there is `null` it will stay `null`.

Comment: okay, sorry. Can I put all the story on document.write ? With all the html tags?

Comment: Don't comment, update main post.

Comment: Yea, maybe I need another language Eugene

Comment: like Eugene has suggested, you could load the content of the current page with `ajax`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look up these functions...

**.classList.toggleClass()** - this allows you to turn a class on and off on an object

**.addEventListener("click", function(), false);** - this turns a click into a function. You would want to put .classList.toggleClass() inside a function so that it can be clicked.

So... with these two things you can make your page 2 button clickable. Your page 1 will start with a class attached with z-index:10... when you click the page 2 button, the z-index class is taken away from page 1, and given to page 2 putting it in front.

Also, clicking the page 2 button will give a class to the page 2 button that makes it disappear (display:none;)... the page 3 button will have already had this invisible class which will then be turned off to make it appear.